# Programmatically reading static links in the navigation

Tags: 2010, development, navigation, object-model

I'm having a SharePoint site where I disabled the "show pages" option in the navigation, and created my navigation using the add static heading/link option. My problem now is that I tried to Programatically read these links, but it seems that topnav.Navigation.GlobalNodes[1].Children is returning all nodes even for those that are hidden (the hidden dynamic nodes for pages). I'm not really sure how can I omit these nodes to get only those explicitly set by the user.

My code is

```
 SPNavigationNodeCollection topnav = _site.Navigation.TopNavigationBar;
                foreach (SPNavigationNode node in topnav.Navigation.GlobalNodes[1].Children)
                {
                    strBuilder.Append("<li>");
                    strBuilder.Append(String.Format("<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>", node.Url, node.Title));
                    if (node.Children.Count > 0)
                    {
                        strBuilder.Append(String.Format("<ul>"));
                        foreach (SPNavigationNode childNode in node.Children)
                        {
                            strBuilder.Append(String.Format("<li><a href='{0}'>{1}</a></li>", childNode.Url, childNode.Title));
                        }
                        strBuilder.Append(String.Format("</ul>"));
                    }
                    strBuilder.Append("</li>");
                }
                strBuilder.Append("</ul>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I found the solution by returning only the nodes with the property bag "NodeType"  not equal to "Page" by the adding the following statement in the top of my outer foreach

```
if ((string) node.Properties["NodeType"] == "Page") continue;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in the quick launch navigation. I solve this issue and describe solution in [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25813/customize-quick-lanch-navigation). I think that it should work in your case, but you should use

```
settings.Parameters["NavigationType"] = PortalNavigationType.Global.ToString();
```

Also this settings does not contain all needed properties. You can open your web.config and find which properties you should add in providers section.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer, but I found a simpler solution for my case. Check my answer below

Comment: I think that in your solution the hidden elements of navigation will be shown.

Comment: No it doesn't... you can try it